# save data from datagridview in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am working on Windows application using vb.net, and Want to save data from datagrdiview which contains the student and check boxes populate according to data in datagrdiview.
based on check box selection i want to save the student ID in database

Comment: I want to Know how to save the data in sql server based on check box selection in vb.net

Comment: make some code based on this : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/278060/Update-checkbox-selected-gridview-row-data-in-data

Comment: I am using windows application , and how I'll use this in windows application using vb.net

Comment: this is simple application. have you googled it once? this is the rule of stackoverflow that, you can not get direct ansers, you have to show your efforts first. Thats why my first comment was asking you for relevent code you have "Tried" for this issue.

Comment: Exactly I googled this problem, but couldn't find any relevant answer for this.